# Redirect the web page to mobile version when screen resolution exceeds

Tags: javascript

I'm using this to redirect the web page to mobile version when screen resolution exceeds 780px :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (window.screen.width <= 780px) {
window.location = "mobile.html";
}

</script>
```

But it isn't working for me. Any errors in my code ?

Answer (score 2):

You have 780px which is a syntax error.

Try

```
if (document.body.clientWidth <= 780) {
    window.location.href = "mobile.html";
}
```

A good idea is allways to open your browsers console when working with javascript ( press F12 in most browsers ). All the errors will show up there.

Comment: That wasn't the hardest task for today @jperelli

Comment: @DivyaKumari, see all the code in the answer, you need to use also `window.location.href`, not `window.location`